# How can i increment session value one on first page using php?

Tags: php

I need to increment session value from one,now can possible to increment from starting two only.How to increment from starting one in first page?

Actually i am trying to increment receipt number in pdf page.

can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Here's my code:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    //$_SESSION['rid']=0;
    if(!empty($_POST['register']))
    {   
        $_SESSION['rid'] = $_SESSION['rid']+ 1;
require("fpdf/fpdf.php");

    $pdf=new FPDF();
    $pdf->Addpage();
$pdf->SetFont("Arial","B",18);
    $pdf->Cell(0,10,"Receipt number:".$_SESSION['rid'],0,0,'C');
    $pdf->output();

    }
?>
```

Comment: `$_SESSION['rid']=0;` and `$_SESSION['rid'] = $_SESSION['rid']+ 1;` means value is 1 in first iteration... whats the problem???

Comment: @Ali Arshad-Thank you,Yes,i am getting value is 1 in first iteration if set like $_SESSION['rid']=0,but i cant able to increment that into  2,3 and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ooh I got your question now. You can do something like this:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if(!isset($_SESSION['rid']))$_SESSION['rid']=0;

    if(!empty($_POST['register']))
    {   
    $_SESSION['rid'] = $_SESSION['rid']+ 1;
require("fpdf/fpdf.php");

    $pdf=new FPDF();
    $pdf->Addpage();
$pdf->SetFont("Arial","B",18);
    $pdf->Cell(0,10,"Receipt number:".$_SESSION['rid'],0,0,'C');
    $pdf->output();

    }
?>
```

Comment: ooh really thanks Ali arshad,its working perfectly,now i can increment from starting 1.really appreciated your answer :)

Comment: now i also can possible to increment again from starting 1 after destroy previously incremented values using session destroy.

Comment: Really thanks for helped Ali Arshad..,happy coding for u too :D

Comment: -Can u also help me to insert these session values into database table?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 on first iteration because you work with sessions, value save in sessions between requests.
Why you use session? Use variable for that or set `$_SESSION['rid'] = 0` on every iteration

Comment: -Thank you,oh ok,but i cant increment into 2,3 if set like $_SESSION['rid'] = 0,In first iteration taking value 1,but i cant able to increment it from 1.